# How to use click() and change() doing the same thing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click

Basically I have to send to a Servlet via ajax some data. And that data should be send when I click `<input id='nextP>'` or `<input id="prevP"`. Until here everthing ok. 
But I have the third element which is `<select id="SelectedPage">` with many options. I tried to use `$('#nextP, #prevP, #SelectedPage').click(function() {.../* the instructions here */...})`, but the problem is that the `#SelectedPage` will send twice data to Servlet. Once when I click the `<select>` and second when I choose the option. Normally I  have to use the `change()` function for the `<select>` tag, that means the code will be twice in my .js page. Is there any possibility to combine both, change and click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code into a function - and use that function for both handlers:

```
function myFunc() {
    //some stuff
}

$("#nextP, #prevP").click(myFunc);
$("#SelectedPage").change(myFunc);
```